# Error with Subliminal tests, Xcode 5.0.2

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, automated-tests, subliminal

Have Subliminal framework, install that through cocoa pods. Xcode version 5.0.2. My first test is worked first time, but now system hangs when executing a test run indefinitely with the words "Tests are starting up..." I can't to publish screenshot,because have low reputation in this web-site...

How I can fix it???